# The order of Cesaro convergent nonnegative sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a real sequence s.t. $a_i \geq0$ and $(1/N)\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i$ is convergent.

I wish to show that $\frac{\max_{1\leq i \leq N} a_i}{N} \to 0$ as $N\to \infty$.

Comment: I really did try. The only thing I can prove is that $a_N/N \to 0$.

Comment: You should add that to your question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N a_i$.
Note that 
$$ \frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N a_i = \frac{a_N}N+\frac {N-1}{N}\left(\frac1{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}a_i\right)$$
Let $\epsilon>0$.
For $N$ sufficiently big, the left hand side and the second summand on the right differ from $a$ by at most $\frac \epsilon2$, hence $\frac{a_N}{N}<\epsilon$ for almost all $N$, say for all $N>N_0$.
Then for such $N$ $$\frac{\max_{1\le i\le N} a_i}{N} \le \max\left\{\frac{\max_{1\le i\le N_0}a_i}{N},\epsilon\right\}.$$
Thus if additionally $N>\frac{\max_{1\le i\le N_0}a_i}{\epsilon}$, we have 
$$ 0\le\frac{\max_{1\le i\le N} a_i}{N}\le \epsilon.$$